# SVG image not rendering in lightbox

Tags: svg, lightbox, lightbox2

My svg image renders on it's own, but will not display on lightbox. In other words, if you click the link, lightbox opens up but NO image. If I replace the svg with a png version, it shows. And like I said before, if I stick the svg image anywhere else on the site without using lightbox, including opening it on a page by itself, it renders perfectly. Are there any svg limitations with lightbox that I'm not aware of?? Thanks!!!

Comment: Which are you using lightbox or lightbox2?

Comment: Robert, I was actually using magnific popup, not lightbox. And it seems the issue was occurring with Chrome, as everything was working fine in other browsers. That said, I switched over to slimebox2 and am having no more issues. Thanks for the reply.